# Javascript - Generate random small intervals in a range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I am trying to generate random intervals between the range: 2,5k - 10M.

Currently, I am doing the following:

```js
const MIN_NUMBER = 2500;
const MAX_NUMBER = 10000000;

const random = (min, max, floating = false) => {
  const result = Math.random() * max + min;
  return floating ? result : Math.floor(result);
};

const min = random(MIN_NUMBER, MAX_NUMBER / 10);
const max = random(min, min * 10);
const interval = `[${min}, ${max}]`;

console.log(interval);
```

But as you can see, the probability that the generated interval is small/medium is not very high.

I want to get random intervals like:

- [2500, 10400]
- [2500, 9919]
- [3000000, 3301029]
- [500000, 611223]

I am not following any specific rule, but as you can see, in relation with

- [2500, 400000]
- [2500, 71000]
- [3000000, 10000000]
- [500000, 3120000]

they are considered "small/medium", because there is not a "really huge" diff between the max and the min).

With my current algorithm, you can check that the generated average diff is high:

```js
const MIN_NUMBER_OF_LIKES = 2500;
const MAX_NUMBER_OF_LIKES = 10000000;

const random = (min, max, floating = false) => {
  const result = Math.random() * max + min;

  return floating ? result : Math.floor(result);
};

let averageDiff = 0;
const numIterations = 1000;

for (let i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
  const min = random(MIN_NUMBER_OF_LIKES, MAX_NUMBER_OF_LIKES / 10);
  const max = random(min, min * 10);
  averageDiff += max - min;
}

averageDiff /= numIterations;

console.log({ averageDiff });
```

How can I do for getting random small segments instead?

--Note: the difference between the randomly generated intervals is random too, but it has to be "small/medium" (not as huge as with my current solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about first choosing random size of interval within the size you wish - so you get the value of INTERVAL_SIZE. As second step you randomly find the minimum between MIN_NUMBER_OF_LIKES and MAX_NUMBER_OF_LIKES - INTERVAL so you get STARTPOINT.
So final INTERVAL will have STARTPOINT and ENDPOINT = STARTPOINT + INTERVAL_SIZE

Comment: Thx, that is. I will share the code solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @krnz solution:

```js
const MIN = 2500;
const MAX = 10000000;

const random = (min, max, floating = false) => {
  const result = Math.random() * max + min;

  return floating ? result : Math.floor(result);
};

function generateRandomSmallInterval() {
  const intervalSize = random(1000, 10000);
  const start = random(MIN, MAX-intervalSize);
  const end = start + intervalSize;

  return {start, end};
}

const interval = generateRandomSmallInterval();

console.log({ interval });
console.log(`Diff: ${interval.end - interval.start}`);
```

---

Refactored and generalized code using lodash:

```
import { random } from 'lodash';

function generateRandomIntervalInRange(min, max, maxIntervalSize = max - min) {
  if (max - min <= 0) {
    throw new Error("The `max` argument must be greater than `min`.");
  }

  if (maxIntervalSize <= 0) {
    throw new Error("The maximum interval size must be greater than 0.");
  }

  if (maxIntervalSize > max - min) {
    throw new Error(
      `The maximum interval size mustn't be greater than ${max - min}.`
    );
  }

  const intervalSize = random(1, maxIntervalSize);
  const start = random(min, max - intervalSize);
  const end = start + intervalSize;

  return { start, end };
}

//
// MAIN
//

const MIN = 1;
const MAX = 10;
const MAX_INTERVAL_SIZE = 5;

console.log(generateRandomIntervalInRange(MIN, MAX, MAX_INTERVAL_SIZE));
```